# MySQL concurrent connections - loading text from database

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

If I have a single page, which its contents are generated from a MySQL database (simple query to display the contents of a cell, HTML contents), how many users can hit that page at once without crashing the database?

I have to display the same data across multiple domains, so instead of duplicating the page on three domains, I'm going to load it into mysql and use this route to display it. However, I want to find out how many concurrent connections I could handle without crashing the database.

Can anyone point me in the right directions to finding this out? I'm assuming this small query shouldn't be a huge load, but if 10,000 visitors hit it at once, then what?

Comment: This depends on your server's hardware and software/OS. If you think your server won't be able to handle it, look into load balancing with multiple servers like large websites typically do. Also consider caching the database output which will ensure less calls are made to your database.

Comment: Also keep in mind that MySQL uses a query cache of its own, so if you fire the same query 10,000 times, MySQL will typically not recalculate the results unless the tables you are querying change. Instead, MySQL will answer the query from its query cache. This can hugely boost performance: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

For more static data and larger queries, however, it can be worthwhile to generate the table just once, store the HTML somewhere, and simply send that the user's way. Updated your table? Then you update the HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check ur setting for max_connections, you could get more information about this by looking at the following link: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/update-max-connections-mysql/

Are you using any framework? If so most have caching built into them which should solve the issue assuming that the information isn't being updated on a moment to moment basis. Even if it is, try to cache whatever parts of the page you assume are not going to change that often.

Answer (score 0):

> how many users can hit that page at once without crashing the database?

All of them.

It's a bad question.

The database should not crash because users are trying to connect. There are lots of limits on how many php clients can open concurrent connections to the database. Really you should have the DBMS correctly configured so it handles the situation gracefully - i.e. max_connections should limit the number of clients - not the amount of memory available to the DBMS.

If you mean how many concurrent connections can you support without connections being rejected / queued, that's something VERY different. And it's nearly a sensible question.

In that case, it's going to depend on the amount of memory you've got, how you've configured the DBMS, how fast the CPU is, what size the content is, how many content items there are, how PHP connects to the DBMS, how far away the PHP is from the DBMS....

You're more likely to run into connection limits on the webserver before you hit them on the DBMS - but the method for establishing what those limits are is the same for both - generate a controlled number of connection and measure how memory it uses - repeat for a different number, get lots of data. Draw a graph, see where the line crosses your resource limits.

> so instead of duplicating the page on three domains, I'm going to load it into mysql

The number of domains is pretty much irrelevant - unless you're ecxplicitly looking for a method of avoiding ESI.

> but if 10,000 visitors

Really? On a typical site that would mean perhaps a million concurrent HTTP sessions.